# Offset when converting String to Date

Tags: java, date, date-format, simpledateformat

I have to convert string to Date.
For that I am using :

```
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd");
    Date date = formatter.parse( "2016-01-26" );
    System.out.println("Date:"+date);
```

But the output I am getting is Date:

`Tue Jan 26 00:01:00 IST 2016`

instead of Date:

`Tue Jan 26 00:00:00 IST 2016`.

Can anyone please explain why I am getting an offset of 1 min (00:01:00)

Comment: Try `"yyyy-MM-dd"`, so the *month* is not interpreted as **minute**.

Comment: Its correct. `mm` for minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using format `yyyy-MM-dd`.

**mm is minutes** whereas **MM is months**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date date = formatter.parse("2016-01-26");
        System.out.println("Date:" + date);
    }
```

**Output**

```
Date:Tue Jan 26 00:00:00 IST 2016
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set 'MM'. Small 'mm' is used for minute. Please check the below link for all format

try this code.

```
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date date = formatter.parse( "2016-01-26" );
    System.out.println("Date:"+date);
```

Check below format

y = year

Q = quarter

M = month

w = week of year

W = week of month

d = day of the month

D = day of year

E = day of week

a = period (AM or PM)

h = hour (1-12)

H = hour (0-23)

m = minute

s = second